# Logarithmic generating function

Tags: polynomials, summation, generating-functions

I'm fairly new to generating functions, but I'm encountering some sums that I think are amenable to logarithmic generating functions. 
One particular sum has the form 
$$f(x)=\sum_{n}\frac{f_{2n}}{n}x^{2n}$$
In this case I know what $g(x)=\sum_{n}f_{2n}x^{2n}$ sums to, and I can derive an expression for $f(x)$ by substituting $x\rightarrow\sqrt{x}$ into $g(x)$ and integrating on $x$, but I also know that $f(x)$ should be a logarithm of a finite polynomial in $g$. 
Is it possible to use some composition theorem to show that actually $f(x)=\ln P(g(x))$ without the substitutions and integrations?

Comment: I don't see the $\log$ and $P$ coming, since $f'(x)=2\sum\limits_{n}f_{2n}x^{2n-1} \Rightarrow xf'(x)=2g(x)$, but this is rather generic. Do you have a specific case/example?